# Mount command can not contain Chinese characters

Tags: macos, terminal, mount, smb

I encounter a problem,

I want to mount a shared remote directory, but the url has Chinese characters.

```
mount_smbfs //user:password@192.168.1.168/图片 /Volumes/picture
```

图片 are Chinese characters, which mean picture in English.

When I execute this command, I get below error:

> mount_smbfs: URL parsing failed, please correct the URL and try again: Invalid argument 
>   16384

I can confirm it is caused by the Chinese character, because I can execute below command:

```
mount_smbfs //user:password@192.168.1.168/hehe /Volumes/picture
```

Both hehe and 图片 are remote shared directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the unicode

图片 translates as  %E5%9B%BE%E7%89%87 using an escape function I found online at http://www.url-encode-decode.com

The app [UnicodeChecker](http://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/) installs a service which can convert any unicode character string into percent escapes.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912811/what-is-the-proper-way-to-url-encode-unicode-characters for a reference.

Comment: Thank you both. It works. The Chinese characters should be encoded before sent. It can also be done by python command urllib.parse.quote('图片')